# Winter Bash dropdown header wrong background color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash-2016

The background color of the winter bash dropdown is declared as nice bright ice-cold blue (I believe the same color that the design was in previous years), instead of the dark midnight blue this year's design uses...

Which means that I get a flash of this:

> [image]

Before getting this:

> [image]

It's a tad annoying.

Just for reference, it should be `#3b3c5a`, not `#8fd8f6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated the header background color to fit with the current theme.